# how to add ads with animation on the navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, iad

How can i add ads with animation on to the navigation bar, for example i have some product offers ad for which i need to animate the text showing some multiple offers of the product in the same ad?

Comment: Is it so hard to read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an `IBAction` for `UIButton` and in this action you can change navigation bar title

```
-(IBAction)yourBtnPress:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"your title";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationItem.title=@"the title";
```

Answer (score 2):

Supposing navBar is you navigation bar, use

```
navBar.topItem.title = @"String with your title";
```

Note that navBar should be an IBOutlet.

Answer (score 2):

it should be.

```
self.title=@"title text";
```

`self` should be `UIViewController` Type

Answer (score 1):

just give `IBOutlet` and action to every button with this methods

```
-(IBAction)btn1_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"ONE";// laso you can use self.title = @"ONE";
}

-(IBAction)btn2_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"TWO";
}

-(IBAction)btn3_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"THREE";
}

-(IBAction)btn4_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"FOUR";
}

-(IBAction)btn5_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"FIVE";
}

-(IBAction)btn6_Clicked:(id)sender
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"SIX";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Code.

```
-(IBAction)Btn1Pressed:(id)sender 
{
    self.title=@"ONE";
}

-(IBAction)Btn2Pressed:(id)sender
{
    self.title=@"TWO";
}
```

And so on..

Answer (score 1):

It seems like about every answer has been covered, but I guess I'll add this any way. I'm more of a fan of one IBAction that sets the title to an item in an array corresponding to the buttons tag. You would have to add tags to all of your buttons (0 - 5), and I'm not sure if interface builder will allow you to link multiple buttons to the same IBAction, but you could always to it programmatically!

```
- (IBAction)changeTitle:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ONE",@"TWO",@"THREE",@"FOUR",@"FIVE",@"SIX", nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:[temp objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
    temp = nil;
}
```